# Linear algebra - easy proof

Tags: linear-algebra

This one comes from Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra. Pick any numbers $x+y+z = 0$. Find an angle between $\mathbf v=(x,y,z)$ and $\mathbf w=(z,x,y)$.

Explain why $$\dfrac{\bf v\cdot w}{\bf \Vert v\Vert \cdot\Vert w\Vert}$$ is always $-0.5$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x+y+z = 0$, then $0 = (x+y+z)^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx) = \|v\| \cdot \|w\| + 2 v \cdot w$.

Rearranging gives the result $\dfrac{v \cdot w}{\|v\| \cdot \|w\|} = -\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(***)$ be the equation, then $$(***) = \frac{xz+xy+yz}{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \frac{x(-x)+yz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}
\\ = \frac{-x^2 + 1/2\cdot[(y+z)^2-y^2-z^2]}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \\
=  \frac{-x^2 + 1/2\cdot[x^2 - y^2 - z^2]}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \\
= \frac{(-1/2)\cdot (x^2+y^2+z^2)}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \\ =  -1/2,$$ as desired.